# Time in UTC HEX format. How to convert to normal time?

Tags: sql-server, time, timestamp, hex

I have some application for dataaquistion from 3rd party developer company. The timestamps are saved by the app to a unknown format. The column in the MSSQL 2008 database is named "UTC" and datatype is varchar(32).

```
Timestamp sample:

2455832.07550638:000000A9
2455832.07552953:00000173
2455832.07555267:0000023B
2455832.07557582:00000303
```

Is anybody know how to convert via MSSQL query ?

Comment: What dates/times are these meant to be please? Without that, how can we know?

Comment: @gbn: I bet it's Tue Sep 27 2011, 13:48 UTC (between 13:48:43 and 13:48:49).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about MSSQL, but your timestamp format (the part to the left of the colon) looks like Julian dates: the number of (fractional) days elapsed since noon, Jan 1, 4713 BC (UT). From the number of decimal digits, the time resolution seems to be about one millisecond. You can convert Julian dates to a Unix timestamp simply by `unix_timestamp = (jd-2440587.5)*86400`. I don't get the meaning of the second field (the hexadecimal part), but I guess it's not part of the timestamp.